# How do I change the cursor face per buffer?

Tags: major-mode, faces

I have a custom emacs major-mode which I specified the background and foreground colors for. However, the default cursor color clashes with the background and you can't see it.

'set-cursor-color' changes the color for the entire emacs session which is undesirable. I tried using a mode-hook where I set the 'cursor' face locally using ['make-local-variable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784417/setting-font-lock-face-to-different-values-for-different-major-modes), that didn't work either (I saw no effect), I did see an effect if I set a font-lock face though, so I think the code is correct.

My guess is that the cursor is actually only settable as a global variable and is not evaluated per buffer. Is there a way I can set the cursor color per buffer so that it doesn't clobber the cursor color for other buffers? Or maybe is there a way where I can detect that I am 'entering' and 'leaving' the buffer and set the cursor color appropriately?

Comment: According to `C-h f set-cursor-color` (docstring) the color is set for each emacs frame (what's usually called a window outside emacs).

Answer (score 1):

I (I'm the OP) figured out an (imperfect) way to do it using `buffer-list-update-hook` (which happens whenever you switch buffers or windows https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers#toc8).

First I store the original cursor color:

`(setq orig-cursor-background (face-attribute 'cursor :background))`

Then whenever `buffer-list-update-hook` runs I just check the `major-mode` variable and see if it matches my major mode. If it does, then I set the cursor color to what I want using `set-face-background`. Otherwise I set it to `orig-cursor-background`.

The problem with this approach is that every buffer in the frame will also have the cursor changed until you switch buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Library [`cursor-chg.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/cursor-chg.el) shows you how to do this.  See `change-cursor-mode`.

Essentially, you can change the cursor type or color using a function on `post-command-hook` or on a major mode hook.

For example:

```
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'my-cursor-change)

(defun my-cursor-change ()
  (set-cursor-color (if SOME-TEST "Orange" "Blue")))
```

Comment: `set-cursor-color` seems to set a frame parameter. I tried using `set-cursor-color` on a minor-mode hook, but it seems to result in the wrong color sometimes, and I'm curious if the setting of a frame parameter could explain this. I'm wondering if there's a buffer-local solution which might address the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As to the *first* question ("*Is there a way I can set the cursor color per buffer so that it doesn't clobber the cursor color for other buffers?*"), the answer is:  "No, this is not presently an available feature."

As described by @JeanPierre in the initial comment underneath the question above, cursor color is set on a per-frame basis -- i.e., *not* on a per-buffer basis, and *not* on a per-window basis.  Therefore, all visible windows on the same frame will be affected by a change in cursor color made from anywhere inside said frame.

As to the *second* question ("*Or maybe is there a way where I can detect that I am 'entering' and 'leaving' the buffer and set the cursor color appropriately?*"), see the other answers in this thread.

One idea the original poster may wish to consider is experimenting with the variable `cursor-in-non-selected-windows`, which could perhaps be used in conjunction with the other answers to completely remove or change the type of cursor in non-selected windows.