# How to make a thin red cursor

Tags: cursor

This is a newbie question.

I'd like to have a red cursor with a width of 4. This code doesn't work:

```
(setf cursor-type '(bar . 4))
(set-cursor-color "#FF0000")
```

how can i correct this to display a red cursor with a width of 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `cursor-type` is a buffer-local variable, if you use `setf` (or `setq`) you only change its value in the temporary buffer used while reading the init file ([ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681167/modify-syntax-entry-is-not-loaded-in-emacs-init#comment70559656_41681167)). When a variable's doc string says "Automatically becomes buffer-local when set" it means you have to use `setq-default` to change it.
This works for me

```lisp
(setq-default cursor-type '(bar . 4))
(set-cursor-color "#FF0000") ; You can also use ‘"red"’.
```

---

From the comments: You can change the shape of the cursor in unselected windows by setting `cursor-in-non-selected-windows`, for example `(setq-default cursor-in-non-selected-windows '(bar . 1))`.

Comment: This is great except I can no longer can distinguish between two cursors in two different emacs windows. I can't distinguish which is current buffer, ie, the buffer in focus. Both are red. Is there a way I can hide the inactive cursor and make it invisible? Or maybe just make it light grey?

Comment: @WickedJargon You can change the shape of the cursor in the unselected windows by changing `cursor-in-non-selected-windows`, for example `(setq-default cursor-in-non-selected-windows '(bar . 1))`, or you can make it invisible by setting the variable to `nil` (see `C-h v cursor-in-non-selected-windows` for all the options). Regarding the color, I don't know how make Emacs use a different one for the unselected windows' cursor. Maybe [How do I change the cursor face per buffer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27495/how-do-i-change-the-cursor-face-per-buffer) is of help?